# jquery draggable causing the screen to scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, draggable

Here is my setup: I got a div on my main page with links, they are draggable. This works.

I now got an iframe. If something is clicked on the iframe it replaces the content within a div on the main page (ajax call to update the div on the main page). This works, but now draggable does not work.

Here is code within the php page in the iframe:
http://pastebin.com/Qy70D3YH

note: doa() func is called onclick for links within the iframe.

The problem: Other then ", parent.document" testabv() this is a copy/paste of the function call in the root/top page. This does not work. When I use this code and try to drag something the entire screen scrolls down as a move the mouse while dragging.

edit: I am not sure how to fix this, because even if its not scrolling it does not seem to call the droppable class.... But I did find a workaround.... Instead my iframe code is now calling my root/top page function to make it draggable within the success event: window.parent.taskDraggable(); So in other words, the top/root function that has always worked is now doing all the work instead of trying to make it work within the iframe.

Comment: please use http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of doing this I can think of

1. Try adding a class that has `overflow: hidden` to the body and toggle when you're dragging.
2. Disable scroll-related events. Here's a JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/disable-scrolling/1

Answer (score 0):

Set elem scroll to false

```
$(elem).draggable({

            helper: "clone",
            revert: 'invalid',
            scroll: false,
            scrollSensitivity: 100,
            scrollSpeed: 50,

        });
```